# running turtlesim in windows 10 makes error

Tags: ros2, turtlesim, pyqt

I have installed ros2 foxy in my system(due to go with a ROS2 tutorial) and according to the document which ros provides , I did it OK and also I run talker and listener example and it is OK.
the problem is when I use the tutorial step by step and I open a x64 native visual studio and  run ros2 "run turtlesim turtlesim_node" it returns:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins\platforms"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I have searched all over accessible data and checked everywhere but error stays yet.
please help me to do it.